# C++ check if any user is logged in to windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I use psexec to run my app,
Some of the tasks my app does should have a logged on user,
so I want to check (from the app, not the server which runs the psexec)
if there is a user which currently logged on. I couldn't find any api which retrieve this. My code is in c++.
Any idea to check it?

Comment: Logged on via the console, or a virtual windowstation such as remote desktop?

Comment: Doesn't matter if via console or remote desktop. Found a solutio n using the registry keys under HKLM

Answer (score 6):

use [LsaEnumerateLogonSessions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) + [LsaGetLogonSessionData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution to this issue
I enumerate the registry keys (using RegEnumKeyEx) under HKEY_USERS.
If there is a key different from the default ones (".DEFAULT","S-1-5-18","S-1-5-19","S-1-5-20") it means that at least on user is logged on